# Cron job to remove logically redundant entries in Postgres SQL

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc, job-scheduling

I have a requirement to delete records from a Postgres SQL table which has more than 200 million records. The table is not having any primary key.

The sample table (Bookmark is the name of table) content is as below:

```
systemId     filename           mindatetime                 maxdatetime
  70277     monitor_1.dat   2019-04-21 08:00:00 AM      2019-04-21 03:10:00 PM
  10006     monitor_2.dat   2019-04-25 10:00:00 AM      2019-04-25 11:30:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 08:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 10:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 11:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 04:00:00 PM
  8368      monitor_1.dat   2019-05-21 11:00:00 AM      2019-05-21 11:30:00 AM
  8368      monitor_7.dat   2019-05-21 06:00:00 AM      2019-05-21 11:00:00 AM
  8368      monitor_5.dat   2019-05-23 08:00:00 AM      2019-05-23 10:00:00 AM
  72777     monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 11:00:00 AM
  72777     monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 11:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 18:00:00 PM
  72777     monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:30:00 AM      2019-04-29 23:00:00 PM
  12345     monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 10:00:00 AM
  12345     monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 02:00:00 PM      2019-04-28 06:00:00 PM
  12345     monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 03:00:00 PM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 09:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-04-29 09:01:00 AM      2019-04-30 10:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-04-30 10:01:00 AM      2019-04-30 11:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-05-12 07:00:10.001 AM  2019-05-13 10:00:10.000 AM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-05-15 09:30:10.001 AM  2019-05-18 11:30:10.000 AM
```

The cron job should run on a given schedule to delete the records which are logically redundant.

To explain this let's take the case of systemId '10006' where filename is 'monitor_3.dat' having 3 entries with min and max date timestamp of the same day.

Logically we can delete the entries having mindatetime 08:00:00 AM and 09:00:00 AM, maxdatetime 10:00:00 AM, 11:00:00 AM as that interval is being covered by the other entry which has mindatetime as 7 AM and maxdatetime as 4 PM.

So those entries would fall under this interval and the job should identify such entries in the entire table and delete them.

My resultant output table content in this case should be:

```
 systemId    filename           mindatetime                 maxdatetime
  70277     monitor_1.dat   2019-04-21 08:00:00 AM      2019-04-21 03:10:00 PM
  10006     monitor_2.dat   2019-04-25 10:00:00 AM      2019-04-25 11:30:00 AM
  10006     monitor_3.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 04:00:00 PM
  8368      monitor_1.dat   2019-05-21 11:00:00 AM      2019-05-21 11:30:00 AM
  8368      monitor_7.dat   2019-05-21 06:00:00 AM      2019-05-21 11:00:00 AM
  8368      monitor_5.dat   2019-05-23 08:00:00 AM      2019-05-23 10:00:00 AM
  72777     monitor_4.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-29 23:00:00 PM
  12345     monitor_5.dat   2019-04-28 07:00:00 AM      2019-04-28 06:00:00 PM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-04-28 09:00:00 AM      2019-04-30 11:00:00 AM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-05-12 07:00:10.001 AM  2019-05-13 10:00:10.000 AM
  10006     monitor_8.dat   2019-05-15 09:30:10.001 AM  2019-05-18 11:30:10.000 AM
```

The table size is more than 20Gb on disk so I was exploring writing a sql procedure or job to achieve this but not able to make much progress. Any ideas or suggestions for overcoming this complex scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tsranges to look for overlap.  The query would be a bit simpler if there were a unique key and you may run into issues if there are duplicate rows, but here's the basic idea:

```
-- The rows to be deleted:

select * from bookmark WHERE exists
(select 1 from bookmark bm2
  WHERE bm2.systemid = bookmark.systemid
   AND  bm2.filename = bookmark.filename
   AND  (bookmark.systemid, bookmark.filename, bookmark.mindatetime, bookmark.maxdatetime) IS DISTINCT FROM (bm2.systemid, bm2.filename, bm2.mindatetime, bm2.maxdatetime)
   AND tsrange(bookmark.mindatetime, bookmark.maxdatetime, '[]') <@ tsrange(bm2.mindatetime, bm2.maxdatetime, '[]')
);
 systemid |   filename    |     mindatetime     |     maxdatetime
----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------
    10006 | monitor_3.dat | 2019-04-28 08:00:00 | 2019-04-28 10:00:00
    10006 | monitor_3.dat | 2019-04-28 09:00:00 | 2019-04-28 11:00:00
    72777 | monitor_4.dat | 2019-04-28 11:00:00 | 2019-04-29 18:00:00


-- Delete them like so:

delete from bookmark WHERE exists
(select 1 from bookmark bm2
  WHERE bm2.systemid = bookmark.systemid
   AND  bm2.filename = bookmark.filename
   AND  (bookmark.systemid, bookmark.filename, bookmark.mindatetime, bookmark.maxdatetime) IS DISTINCT FROM (bm2.systemid, bm2.filename, bm2.mindatetime, bm2.maxdatetime)
   AND tsrange(bookmark.mindatetime, bookmark.maxdatetime, '[]') <@ tsrange(bm2.mindatetime, bm2.maxdatetime, '[]')
);
```

Note that this doesn't exactly match your expected output due to a typo in your data.  These two rows do not overlap:

```
72777 | monitor_4.dat | 2019-04-28 09:00:00 | 2019-04-29 11:00:00
72777 | monitor_4.dat | 2019-04-28 09:30:00 | 2019-04-29 23:00:00
```

Unless you are actually looking to update and delete?  In that case, your best bet is probably to create a new table and rename it:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmark_load AS 
  SELECT systemid, filename, min(mindatetime), max(maxdatetime)
  FROM bookmark
  GROUP BY systemid, filename;

ALTER TABLE bookmark RENAME TO bookmark_old;
ALTER TABLE bookmark_load RENAME TO bookmark;
```

Of course, you couldn't be inserting new data into bookmark while doing this.

Comment: I have edited the question with one more scenario for which your code was failing. I need the logical intervals of min and max date time for a given systemid and filename.

Comment: I don't understand how the result table has a row that doesn't exist in the source table.  I thought you just wanted to delete rows.  Was that a typo?

Comment: The SQL query is again failing for one set of input which I have updated in the question itself. Basically when the time ranges are not self contained.

Comment: Which row from your expected output does not match the final query I posted?  The output looks exactly the same to me.

Comment: The one with systemid '12345' I added this later as the query was failing for this

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you; it's there when I run the query with the updated data.

Comment: Can you recheck? I don't see select query returning records for systemid "12345"

Comment: Yes, the last query with the GROUP BY systemid, filename definitely has a row for 12345.

Comment: I see issue with one more case now having systemid '10006'. I am adding these cases now as the records are huge and its difficult for me to put all the cases at once

Comment: Again, the last query, to create a new table, has that row.  You didn't specify this, but I assume the two timestamp columns are actually timestamps and not text?

Comment: Yes, they are timestamps. It is not that straight forward to use min and max over a group of files. Included a scenario with completely unrelated timestamps